# Xamarin.Android native project - build error

Tags: android, xamarin

I use Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise, Mono.Android v4.0.30319.
I created a Xamarin.Android native project, but every time i build it I encounter this problem, someone can help me please ?

Many thanks for your help !

2>CREATEMULTIDEXMAINDEXCLASSLIST : warning : can't write resource [META-INF/MANIFEST.MF] (Duplicate zip entry [android-support-multidex.jar:META-INF/MANIFEST.MF])
2>CREATEMULTIDEXMAINDEXCLASSLIST : warning : can't write resource [META-INF/MANIFEST.MF] (Duplicate zip entry [arch-core-common.jar:META-INF/MANIFEST.MF])
2>CREATEMULTIDEXMAINDEXCLASSLIST : warning : can't write resource [META-INF/MANIFEST.MF] (Duplicate zip entry [arch-lifecycle-common.jar:META-INF/MANIFEST.MF])
2>CREATEMULTIDEXMAINDEXCLASSLIST : error : Can't write [C:\Users\mohamed-ali.nouira\AppData\Local\Temp\sdar2n3m.hco.jar] (Can't read [C:\Users\mohamed-ali.nouira\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.v4\23.4.0.0\embedded\classes.jar] (Duplicate zip entry [classes.jar:android/support/v4/util/ArrayMap.class]))
========== Rebuild All: 1 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========

Comment: Could you please provide your referenced libraries list or a screenshot of that? And which version of Visual Studio 2017 are you using? You can find the version number under `Help->About Microsoft Visual Studio`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment @Elvis Xia -MSFT, I resolved this problem by installing the same version of Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat and Xamarin.Android.Support.v4 !